# Parallax effect on all sections

Tags: css, parallax

https://jsfiddle.net/uoz5rac7/2/

I have a parallax effect here in the first section, but I would like to have it on all sections. If I use `transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);` on the other sections my first sections breaks. 
Is there any way to achieve the same effect like in the first section for others?